# Express - issue parsing query parameters, bad request

Tags: express, httprequest

While testing our Express endpoint we found out that some specific requests with long query strings (`/?x[0]=0&x[1]=1 ... &x[100]=100`) fail. App was responding with **HTTP 400** (bad request). First, we thought that query is too long and that it's being blocked by firewall/nginx or that we are hitting some kind of nodejs/express limitation. However, after some experimentation, we found out that `/?x[21]=21` fails while `/?x[20]=20` works just fine. Why is that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Why it fails?

It turns out that with default express settings:

- call to `/?x[20]=20` results in `req.query.x = [ '20' ]`, while
- call to `/?x[21]=21` results in `req.query.x = { '21': '21' }`.

The second request wasn't passing the validation because we were expecting an array instead of an object.

The reason behind this strange behaviour lies in [qs](https://github.com/hapijs/qs) library that express uses for processing queries.

> qs will also limit specifying indices in an array to a maximum index of 20. Any array members with an index of greater than 20 will instead be converted to an object with the index as the key

### How to fix this?

Qs allows you to change the limit of `20` and express allows you to set your own query parser. So the simplest solution looks like this:

```
app.set('query parser', function (str) {
  return qs.parse(str, {arrayLimit: 1000});
});
```